# const formData = new FormData(); FromData is not working image didn't upload it seems undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, formik

When i submit data from Formik.It didn't work  it seems undefined or image didn't upload to server.it Saved without image and other data uploaded

```
onSubmit={async (values, { resetForm }) => {

            const formData = new FormData();
              formData.append("supplier_name", values.supplier);
              formData.append("file", values.supplierImage[0]);
              formData.append("onboarded_date", moment(values.datepicker).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
              formData.append("country", values.country);
              formData.append("zip_code", values.zip_code);
              formData.append("address_line_1", values.address_1);
              formData.append("address_line_2", values.address_2);

            console.log("values", values.supplierImage)
            if (!id) {
              await post(API_URL.SUPPLIER, formData)
                .then(res => {
                  if (res.data.status === "success") {
                    dispatch(setToast(res.data));
                    resetForm();
                    setError([]);
                    props.history.push("/supplier");
                  }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                  setError(error.data.detail);
                });
            } 
          }}
```

backend response needed like this.our backend is used python django framework.Other data is saved to database but image didn't go to backend

```
Supplier{
id  integer
title: ID
readOnly: true
supplier_name*  string
title: Supplier name
maxLength: 255
minLength: 1
supplier_image  string($uri)
title: Supplier image
readOnly: true
x-nullable: true
onboarded_date* string($date)
title: Onboarded date
country*    string
title: Country
maxLength: 60
minLength: 1
zip_code*   string
title: Zip code
maxLength: 60
minLength: 1
address_line_1* string
title: Address line 1
maxLength: 60
minLength: 1
address_line_2* string
title: Address line 2
maxLength: 60
minLength: 1
```

}

Comment: What is the value of `values.supplierImage[0]`

Comment: check this out https://coderwall.com/p/cjinag/upload-a-image-using-ajax-and-formdata

Comment: values File {name: "Screenshot 2020-04-20 at 4.36.55 PM.png", lastModified: 1587380820911, lastModifiedDate: Mon Apr 20 2020 16:37:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 134741, …}

Comment: that is the values show in submit the value

Comment: Show how you handle it in the server as well

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Supplier{
id integer
title: ID
readOnly: true
supplier_name* string
title: Supplier name
maxLength: 255
minLength: 1
supplier_image string($uri)
title: Supplier image
readOnly: true
x-nullable: true
onboarded_date* string($date)
title: Onboarded date
country* string
title: Country
maxLength: 60
minLength: 1
zip_code* string
title: Zip code
maxLength: 60
minLength: 1
address_line_1* string
title: Address line 1
maxLength: 60
minLength: 1
address_line_2* string
title: Address line 2
maxLength: 60
minLength: 1
 
}

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava that is data i want to sent backend

Comment: Don't post all this as comments, add it to your question

Comment: And I was asking for your backend server code, is it php? express? django?

Comment: django is use backend

Comment: So check how files are being handled in the backed, what is the code for that?

Comment: i have only access to api backend is doing by other team